# SoapUI Pro : Transfering a XML node from a TestCase to another

Tags: soap, soapui

When using the `Property Transfert` window to transfert a XML node (with children nodes) taken from the response of a first Soap request to a second Soap request, and that both requests *are in the same TestCase*, it works great :

**TestCase 1 :**

```
Source : [First Soap Request] Property : [Response]

declare namespace ns='http://xxx.com';
//ns:xxxxx[1]/ns:return[1]

-------------------------------------------
Target : [Second Soap Request] Property : [Request]

declare namespace ser='http://xxx.com';
//ser:xxxxx[1]/ser:someobject[1]
```

But if the two requests are *in different TestCases*, I guess it is required to save the XML node to a *TestSuite property* first, and then transfert this property to the new Soap request :

**TestCase 1 :**

```
Source : [First Soap Request] Property : [Response]

declare namespace ns='http://xxx.com';
//ns:xxxxx[1]/ns:return[1]

-------------------------------------------
Target : [TestSuite1] Property : [myVariableToTransfert]
```

**TestCase 2 :**

```
Source : [TestSuite1] Property : [myVariableToTransfert]

-------------------------------------------
Target : [Second Soap Request] Property : [Request]

declare namespace ser='http://xxx.com';
//ser:xxxxx[1]/ser:someobject[1]
```

This doesn't work!

It seems I'm unable to get valid XML in the second request when it is taken from the TestSuite as a property. Sometimes the value is null, sometimes it is wrapped in CDATA tags or the XML is entitized ("<" are "&lt", for example). I'm unable to get the value as *real XML*, like when both requests are in the same TestCase!

I played with the "Transfert Text Content", "Entitize tranfererred value(s)" and "Transfert Child Nodes" options but without success!

How can I tranfert a XML node from a request in a TestCase to a request in a second TestCase?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the detailed explanation:

Create test suite 1 and the below steps

```
  test case 1
  DataGen step 
  test case 2
```

Within the DataGen step, open the editor, add new property via clicking on "+" button and select script as Type (you should also give a name to the property now assume the name is yourprop).

At the below side of the screen you should see the script editor. And create a script as below (please notie that you should change the variables according to your web service and XML)

```
def testXML = context.expand( '${Test Request#Response#declare namespace ns1=\'http://namespace/'; //ns1:WebServiceNameResponse[1]/ns1:nodeName[1]}' )
```

Now you have created a soapUI property via DataGen named yourprop.  You can use this property within the test suite for the following test cases.

I hope this helps, if you are not satisfied or you face any problem please let me know I will do my best.

Comment: Thanks but I have no idea what you mean. How is this code copying a XML element from a TestCase to another?

Comment: This code does not copy a XML element from one step to another.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: Thank you. I read the Self-Promotion FAQ.  And I know the policy. I have just wrote 5 answers totaly and only in a comment I included a link. This is normal because the original answer does not include a link. You are discouraging me via posting to my every answer.

Comment: I cannot edit my comments that's why I've just deleted. (what I was trying to say is: when I posted the comments I didn't know that I had to disclose that the link belongs to my web site and after learned the rule I could not edit them ) anyway I know the rule and I do not keep doing the same thing. (will disclose if ı give a link that belongs to mey web site)

Comment: @Suha Good! As long as you do that, and observe the other points in the FAQ entry I linked above, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Set your response value as custom property at test suite and then you can use this for further testing..remember it will save your value as string data so if you are saving your integer data then you have to covert it into integer before further use.Like
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("").toInteger()