# Holding object for different testcase

Tags: soapui

Consider I have two testCases in first testcase I created an array using Groovy  now I want to use same array in second testcase.There is any way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dataGen and create the array inside the dataGen.

Create test suite >test case > DataGen step as below

Open the DataGen editor via double clicking on the left menu

Then, click on the + button to add a new property and select 'script'

Now you can create your variables with the groovy scripts.

Comment: I notified you on [Oct 24](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13012015/237838) that it was required for you to disclose every time you are linking to your own website. The blog post you link to also has nothing to do with what is being asked.

Comment: OK I removed the link. However the solution to the question is above. If you want to reuse a data which is created via groovy script. I guess you din not read my post, did you? Please explain me what is wrong with the answer? If you cannot explain the reason that the answer did not match the question please execuse me.

Comment: Hİ user1740631, did my answer help? ıf not please let me know. I will give fırther details.